# Nutch 1.11 Custom Plugin dependency not returning any results

Tags: java, ant, nutch

I am customizing the parse-html plugin for Nutch 1.11 to use tika-1.14 boilerpipe. The intention of the code is to store the boilerpipe results in a metatag field that will be later indexed by Solr. I've used this tecnique before with success. Note: I don't want to replace the content field with boilerpipe - I want the boilerpipe in addition to the full content so I can't just set nutch to use biolerpipe as a default.

I setup a standalone test in eclipse and the Tika code included in the plugin runs find using the tika-app-1.14.jar dependency and returns the expected results.

The parse-html plugin.xml file has been modified to include the tika-1.14.jar file:

```
<runtime>
   <library name="parse-html.jar">
      <export name="*"/>
   </library>
   <library name="tagsoup-1.2.1.jar"/>
   <library name="tika-app-1.14.jar"/>
</runtime>
```

The code compiles fine using Ant 1.9.2.

```
public ParseResult getParse(Content content) {
....

// part of default nutch which contains the full html content for the page
byte[] contentInOctets = content.getContent();

// ====================================
// Print an "I'm Here" message for debugging
String msg = "Tika Boilerpipe Parser";
System.out.println(msg);

// create the Tika stream
org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream stream = 
        org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream.get(contentInOctets);

// create the objects necessary for the boilerpipe
if (stream != null) {
    org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata md = 
            new org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata();
    org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser tikaParser = 
            new org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser();
    org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler tikaTextHandler = 
            new org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler();

    tikaParser.parse(stream,
                    new org.apache.tika.parser.html.BoilerpipeContentHandler(
                            tikaTextHandler), md);

    if (tikaTextHandler != null) { 
        // tikaTextHandler is not null
        System.out.println("md.Title: " + md.get("title"));
        // md.get("title") = null
        metadata.add("emphasis", tikaTextHandler.toString());
        // emphasis = ''
    }
}
System.out.println("Tika End");
// ====================================
```

The Problem is that nothing is being returned from the tikaParser.parse call. It  should populate tikaTextHandler with the boilerpipe results and it dosen't. When running nutch indexchecker or parsechcker, the code completes showing all fields correctly except the emphasis field is blank. I checked to confirm and there are no errors in hadoop.log.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Which version of Nutch are you using? Based on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-961 looks like the boilerpipe support has been merged since v1.12. More over any reason why you're customizing `parse-html` insted of for instance adapting the `parse-tika` plugin that already does the heavy lifting for you?

Comment: Thanks for your response Jorge; the boilerpipe that is merged w/ Nutch will replace the content field with the biolerpipe data. I want both. I'm customizing parse-html because I only want boilerpipe for html & xhtml pages and I thought it would be easier modifying parse-html because that only processes these types. I'm guessing but, it looks like it's a problem with my version of Java. I'm running Nutch on Fedora 24 w/ openJDK 1.7 . I'm going to try this on Debian and let you know (I bet it will work).